# Is this a valid metonymy?

Tags: figures-of-speech

Is this a valid metonymy?

> She flirted with the raunchy snarls of men.

> She flirted with degenerate men.

Are these two the same? I thought you can do this, but someone told me this was nonsensical. Is this the case? What are the rules of metonymy?

Comment: I am a native English speaking person. I have **no** idea what your first sentence is trying to say.  I have **no** idea why a woman would do what your second sentence seems to say.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your examples don’t seem like examples of using metonmy

Changing “She flirted with the raunchy snarls of men.” to read “she flirted with the catcalls and wolf whistles” uses metonymy to imply the snarling raunchy men are represented by catcalls or wolf whistles.

Your second example “She flirted with degenerate men” might be a metonym if you drop the word men and made degenerate plural.  But, it wouldn’t be a great example because equating men to degenerates isn’t a universal statement like equating the waves to the ocean or an election to a race.